# Is there a precedent for a country attacking another and later admitting their casus belli was false?

Tags: international-law, armed-conflict

Is there a precedent for a country attacking another due to unverified information and finding out later they were wrong? And what was the international response?

Narrowing scope: An event that was misunderstood by the attacking side that they later admitted was wrong (specifically of their own accord), but not as part of the post-war surrender process. (i.e. the US striking Syria without declaring war because of, yet unverified, reports of the government using chemical weapons on its own citizens)

Fictional example:

> Country A believes Country B's leader insulted theirs, country A launches missiles/drops bombs/invades territory, short time later Country A realizes that the insult hadn't happened, withdraws and apologizes.

From comments:

> Like the [Ems Dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ems_Dispatch) incident where a bad translation heightened tensions between France and Germany and may have been a factor in the Franco-Prussian war.

Comment: You might want to focus the question.  Asking for hypothetical responses will probably be considered too broad.  Or as opinion based.  'precedent for countries attacking another due to unverified information' might be a better thing to focus on.

Comment: Agreed, I will rework it.

Comment: not sure this will be answerable... most countries of the world are less than free, open and/or transparent.

Comment: @CGCampbell If nothing is found, I assume the answer to there being a precedent would be "no" in that case. Hopefully someone can find an example.

Comment: In that case, it's far too broad a topic..... all of human history? all countries of the world? In case you don't get it, I'm saying there are issues with this question that need to be resolved. Please reduce the scope.

Comment: I'm being partly facetious here... Hitler decided that Europe needed to be cleansed of lesser peoples, and the international response was war. Of course, it was verified that those people were lesser, since there were German scientists that proved the theory, so I guess it wasn't unverified....

Comment: @CGCampbell but new German scientist have repudiated the others, and the state has made apologies. Similarly western hemisphere countries have said some kind things to the decedents of indigenous people who faired poorly under previous policies, and revolutions have blamed deposed rulers for bad things, but I'm not sure that it is in the spirit of the question to count changes in government.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt I was thinking more in terms of a specific event being taken falsely by one side. Like the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ems_Dispatch where a bad translation heightened tensions between France and Germany and may have been a factor in the Franco-Prussian war.

Comment: @CGCampbell I am open to suggestions on narrowing the scope. I do consider your example to be outside it as that is a clash of ideologies rather than a misunderstanding of a specific event.

Comment: @CGCampbell That was never the reason for WWII. The horrible thing is that **Nazi Germany would have likely got away with killing all Jews, homosexuals, criminals and political/religious opponents if they wouldn't started the war**. The thought of lesser beings was widespread and very alive at the time and there was much help from non-Germans in persecuting others. So no, it was starting the war which convinced others that Nazi Germany is a threat.

Comment: So I'm about to go and don't want to type it all here, but the Cold War had quite a few moments where it almost went hot, almost all were due to mistakes on the part of one side or the other or both.  The Cuban Missile Crisis alone has no less than 4 separate incidents that nearly sparked a war.

Comment: It has become widely believed that the USS Maine explosion ws accidental and wasn't bombed by the Spanish. However I don't know if the government of America has admitted this and apologized for starting the Spanish American war..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Gulf of Tonkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_of_Tonkin_incident) incident, if you consider the US statements official enough to count as an admission/apology, and if you count the intensification of the war as a "new" attack.

It is not a completely clear-cut example because *parts* of the US government might have been aware that there was no attack by North Vietnamese torpedo boats.

Comment: This is a good answer, albeit unfortunate that realizing it was a mistake did not stop further attacks and that it wasn't officially admitted until much later. It is not a good precedent, but it is what I asked for. I will wait a while and see if any others are found before I accept.

Comment: I chose this answer over the more highly voted question as I believe it better answered the question I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 10):

Certainly new Governments have done that. [most notably Germany](https://www.economist.com/news/europe/21650183-anniversary-approaches-germany-draws-right-lessons-guilt-and-reconciliation), which is [still trying](http://www.spiegel.de/international/germany-s-nazi-past-why-germans-can-never-escape-hitler-s-shadow-a-345720.html) to deal with its [guilt for world war 2](https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/books/news/germany-has-yet-to-rid-itself-of-its-guilt-over-the-nazis-says-schlink-2082712.html) and the [holocaust](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3548265871).

Comment: Germany had a *casus belli*?

Comment: @user4012 Sure they did - all those Untermenchen occupied this Earth that was rightfully German/Aryan, it called for liberation! Jokes aside, they did have a casus belli for attacking Poland - some kind of a border incident, which, IIRC, was later proven to be a Nazi false flag operation. Modern Germany, AFAIK, never denied that - so the poster's point stands.

Comment: Modern Germany is not the same state that started that war, though. Not sure if this is an answer to the question asked.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov Not according to the German supreme court, which [declared](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsches_Reich#Staatsrechtliche_Fragen_nach_1945) that modern Germany is not a new state, but is indeed identical to the German Reich. Germany has changed since 1945, but it is still Germany, so I think it counts as example answering this question.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov I think you are referring to the [Gleiwitz incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleiwitz_incident) which is the best known false flag attack that preludes ww2. Although there were other similar false flag operations. Hitlers well known speech that declared the start of the invasion of Poland famously said "Since 5:45 we are shooting back", so they did in fact claim that Poland attacked first. Something which pretty much everyone in Germany now knows isn't true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The scope does need to be narrowed. I am looking more for the attacking side admitting they misunderstood an event and were in the wrong of their own accord rather than because of losing a war.

Comment: @tim: Well, that's the legal perspective/definition. The linked article also states that from a political/historical perspective, the German Reich has collapsed.

Comment: @user_42, are you suggesting that Germany only feels guilty for instigating WWII because Germany lost?  That would indicate regret rather than guilt.  I think majority of the Germans genuinely feel guilty about the fact that their country did what it did because of the fact that Germany did it -- not because it worked out badly for Germany.

Comment: @grovkin I am saying it is not applicable to the kind of precedent I am searching for as it was not just one misunderstood event. WWI on the other hand would have been closer to what I am searching for if, hypothetically, Franz Ferdinand was not actually assassinated  but only reported to have been.

Comment: @grovkin To answer your question, I do believe that had Nazi Germany won, there would not have been the same level of guilt put on them. It would be chalked up to the rights of the conqueror/victor. For example, I doubt Genghis Khan, Alexander the Great, the Roman empire, or the Ottoman Empire ever had strong regrets/guilt for the lands or lives they took. As I said, however, I am looking for examples where a leader/country was able to recognize their misunderstanding of an event preferably before it escalated to full-scale conflict.

Comment: `are you suggesting that Germany only feels guilty for instigating WWII because Germany lost?` It's obvious they feel guilty because they lost. Had they won, and the regiome would have collapsed later, they wouldn't feel guilty. (See how modern Russia has zero guilt for the atrocities commited by Soviet Russia).

Comment: @grovkin  Spanish pro-franco supporters do not feel guilt at all for their war crimes and their nazi support during WW2, they are proud of it. because they won.

Comment: @CptEric, Italians do not feel any guilt about the concentration camps, either.  For a good reason, btw.  There had been many cases of Italian army saving (hiding) Jews from being shipped to the death camps.  I my source is a plaque I personally saw in the Holocaust museum in D.C.   But Italy did lose the war along with Germany. So it wasn't just the loss which caused the German guilt. It was the fact that there was indeed something to be guilty about.

Comment: @grovkin in Spain we have over 300.000 bodies in war and post war mass graves, yet there's people that feel proud about the fascist dictatorship, we even have government funded foundations that glorify it. I'm not implying that's why germans feel guilt, i'm saying that it's not completely incompatible the idea of "faking regret as guilt" just to look more democratic, and providing an example of a country that does it, within the same context and within the same conflict periods.

Answer (score 7):

The UK invaded Iraq along side the US, but [later investigations](http://webarchive.nationalarchives.gov.uk/20171123123237/http://www.iraqinquiry.org.uk/) (by Sir John Chilcot) found that the evidence used was either bogus or vastly over-stated. In particular, evidence given to the UN about weapons of mass destruction and to the British Parliament (the so-called "dodgy dossier") are now widely accepted to have been a false pretence.

Comment: The question here is whether the government admitted the mistake, which they didn't.

Comment: The government set up the enquiry and accepted its findings.

Comment: @ugiren: governments don't tend to trumpet their mistakes loudly; an unofficial admission and acceptance through the process of an official inquiry seems valid enough to me.

Answer (score 2):

In reaction after 1998, August 7 [bombings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_United_States_embassy_bombings) of American embassies in Kenya and Tanzania, the USA under Bill Clinton launched [Operation Infinite Reach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Infinite_Reach) against Al-Qaeda sites in Afghanistan and Sudan.

One of the targets, [Al-Shifa pharmaceutical factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Shifa_pharmaceutical_factory) near Khartoum, Sudan, was thought to produce chemical weapons and to have links with Al-Qaeda and Usama Bin Laden. However,

> American officials have acknowledged over the years that the evidence that prompted President Clinton to order the missile strike on the Shifa plant was not as solid as first portrayed. Indeed, officials later said that there was no proof that the plant had been manufacturing or storing nerve gas, as initially suspected by the Americans, or had been linked to Osama bin Laden, who was a resident of Khartoum in the 1980s."

*([The New York Times, 2005](https://www.nytimes.com/2005/10/20/world/africa/look-at-the-place-sudan-says-say-sorry-but-us-wont.html))*

While US officials admit a misjudgement, *"Washington still has not ruled out the possibility that El Shifa did, in fact, have some link to chemical weapons production."* (same source), which explains they refuse to apologize to Sudan.

Note that this military strike was **not** accompanied by a war declaration on Sudan, but it was clearly an *attack*.

Comment: The Casus Beli here is the embassy bombings, which were real.

Comment: That's a question of definition. The bombings were the (very real) casus belli for USA's war with Al-Qaeda. The supposed links with Al-Qaeda were the (dubious) casus belli for US strikes against Sudan.